# Having a problem compiling a ERC20 token smart contract - Code inside

Tags: ethereumj

Basically i'm using a cut and paste erc20 token code from this site:

https://hashnode.com/post/how-to-build-your-own-ethereum-based-erc20-token-and-launch-an-ico-in-next-20-minutes-cjbcpwzec01c93awtbij90uzn

NOT SURE IF THIS TEMPLATE IS IS OUTDATED OR NOT

i am not familiar with solidity, but learning atm

Also i'm using the remix IDE with the new interface

---

The error that i'm getting in the Remix IDE solidity compiler is:

ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'uint8'
uint8 public decimal; 25;
^---^

Comment: I compiled the code in Remix selecting compiler 0.4.26 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

That code is from 2017 and is kinda old. Find an updated code or just change the remix compiler version to 0.4.4
In order to change the compiler version, first chose the solidity compiler then at the top you can see a drop down menu for compiler, click it and chose the 0.4.4 compiler.